# is using a pirated software just for learning allowed and then later buying it when you want to use it for earning money e.g. Adobe , visual studio

Tags: work, software, piracy

Thanks in advance to anyone who answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not allowed in Islam and is considered taking over the software owners' rights which is not from Muslims characteristics that are built based on the Prophet (Peace Be Upon Him) characteristics:

> Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, "**I have been sent to perfect good character**."
>
> *Al-Muwatta’ (1614)*

Also, in qur'an, [Surah Al-Nisa (4), Verse 29](https://quran.com/4/29), Allah Almighty said:

In Arabic (the exact wording):

> ...يا أيها الذين آمنوا لا تأكلوا أموالكم بينكم بالباطل إلا أن تكون تجارة عن تراض منكم

In English (in what it means):

> O you who have believed, do not consume one another's wealth unjustly but only [in lawful] business by mutual consent.

Once on Facebook, a man uploaded a video, telling his personal story with such an approach. The story, in a nutshell, is that he used to have a very promising life but everything had suddenly fallen apart, one by one that it triggered him to search for the reason for that. He prayed over and over, asking Allah to get him on the right path. Until one day, he realized that he actually uses software for entertaining and educational purposes, which he obtained them illegally (i,e, got and used the cracked version). They were pdf books. And once he got rid of them all, his life got back on track.

---

The source of the Fatwa: [Source](https://arabhardware.net/forum/showthread.php?t=47618)